# Problema al tratar de subir PDF wordpress este es el mensaje mostrado: You do not have permission to upload files

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Estoy utilizando el plugin Advanced CF7 DB,con el guardo ciertos datos y un pdf correctamente pero cuando quiero editar los datos,los de texto y fecha los guarda correctamente,el problema es con el pdf al intentar subir un nuevo archivo me dice que no tengo permisos aun siendo yo administrador.

En el cpanel puedo ver que los permisos para carpetas son 755 y para archivos 644,soy novato en wordpress por favor ayuda...
dejo adjunto imagen de las carpetas del host donde se ven los permisos y del error[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tampoco soy experto, pero tal vez esto te ayude: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod#Asignaci%C3%B3n_de_permisos_en_el_comando_chmod por si quieres probar con ellos

Comment: gracias,si probé cambiando los permisos pero se daño el panel de administración de wordpress y no quise seguir cambiando esos privilegios por temor a romper el sitio

Comment: Al subir los pdf con ese plugin debe de hacerlo a un directorio en concreto, comprueba que ese directorio tiene los permisos correctamente asignados.